# how to limit the label size only for bubble diameter in high charts

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

In my high charts some bubbles have long labels.I need to limit that label only for diameter size of of that bubble. (As a example flowing graph XIMT-DL should be XIMT...). Do you know the way to do that?

`code example`: [code example](https://jsfiddle.net/heshanjay/3rvs26kc/3/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this behavior is not implemented in the core. However, it can be achieved easily by implementing your custom logic. In the `chart.events.render` callback check the width of each point and width of its data label. When data label is wider than the point just trim it and add dots if necessary. Check the code and 
demo posted below:

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    type: 'packedbubble',
    height: '100%',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this;

        chart.series.forEach(series => {
          series.points.forEach(point => {

            if (point.graphic.width > 1) {
              if (point.dataLabel.width > point.graphic.width) {
                let indic = (
                    (point.dataLabel.width - point.graphic.width) /
                    point.dataLabel.width
                  ),
                  text = point.series.name,
                  textLen = text.length,
                  maxTextLen = Math.floor(textLen * (1 - indic)),
                  newText,
                  dotted,
                  substringLen;

                dotted = maxTextLen > 2 ? '..' : '.';
                substringLen = maxTextLen > 2 ? 2 : 1;
                newText = text.substring(0, maxTextLen - substringLen) + dotted;

                point.dataLabel.text.element.innerHTML =
                  '<tspan>' + newText + '</tspan>';

                point.dataLabel.text.translate(
                  (point.dataLabel.width - point.graphic.width) / 2,
                  0
                );
              }
            }

          });
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2zdLqt3j/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

---

Another approach is to add an event listener `afterRender` and modify labels there so that chart options are defined separately.

**Code:**

```
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Series, 'afterRender', function() {
    console.log(this);

    const chart = this.chart;

    chart.series.forEach(series => {
      if (series.points && series.points.length) {
        series.points.forEach(point => {

          if (point.graphic.width > 1) {
            if (point.dataLabel.width > point.graphic.width) {
              let indic = (
                  (point.dataLabel.width - point.graphic.width) /
                  point.dataLabel.width
                ),
                text = point.series.name,
                textLen = text.length,
                maxTextLen = Math.floor(textLen * (1 - indic)),
                newText,
                dotted,
                substringLen;

              dotted = maxTextLen > 2 ? '..' : '.';
              substringLen = maxTextLen > 2 ? 2 : 1;
              newText = text.substring(0, maxTextLen - substringLen) + dotted;

              point.dataLabel.text.element.innerHTML =
                '<tspan>' + newText + '</tspan>';

              point.dataLabel.text.translate(
                (point.dataLabel.width - point.graphic.width) / 2,
                0
              );
            }
          }

        });
      }
    })
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/er9ahqnb/1/

Comment: I am sending graph model from back end and set front end only disply graphs.this event.render function cannot send from json format. is there any another way to do this?

Comment: I've edited my answer, now you can add this piece of code after Highcharts is loaded and send options using json.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use this with angular. I couldn't able to take point.graphic.width from chart.events.render from angular. it gives as a 0 value

Comment: Sure, check this Angular example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-tst9x. If my answer is helpful please mark it as a correct one and upvote, thanks.